# What is best practice when it comes to reusable UITableViewCell's and delegates?

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegation

I'm building an app that presents table views in a majority of the screens. They present a handful of different table view cells, but there is one that is presented in `3/5` of the table views. This cell, which displays a video and provides an interface for users to interact with the video (like, comment, flag, delete, play/pause, etc), has a fairly large delegate with seven methods/functions.

My question is: 
Would it be a best practice to set up a separate controller that would be a property of my view controller to be assigned as the delegate to the cell, or to subclass a `UITableViewController` with the methods already implemented?

The problems I see with the latter is that I would then have to implement a weird way to handle the data source (set up methods to return the models, always ensure that videos are stored in that array) and the former just seems a little odd to the standard MVC practice. Any advice?

**Update**

I began factoring out a data source to use that implements the cell's protocol. Another issue that I seem to be running into is displaying multiple cells, i.e.:

I have a `searchDisplayController` that displays `UserCell`'s and `VideoCell`'s, based on the `selectedScopeIndex` of the search bar. One way I could handle this is to create a dataSource for this tableView that handles both cases, or swap out data sources based on changes to the `selectedScopeIndex`. Are either of the two options looked down upon? Is swapping a table view's data source valid?

Comment: Your question is not 100% clear for me, if you have the same cell in many places, you may want to externalize your UITableViewDataSource in a class, so that can be re-used wherever you need it, are you asking for some direction to do it?

Comment: I've pulled out the data source and I'm having some issues with the general design because of the complexities involved with having a table view cell play a video (play/pause at certain Y values in the view controller's view, pushing controllers, triggering UI events, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by implementing a `UITableViewDataSource` controller that would also handle the cell's delegates. I was able to shorten the 7 method delegate to a 3 method delegate on the data source, used to push new controllers, remove objects from the data model, and handle fading/updates.

Granted, I needed to pass reference to the `UITableView`, the `UIView`, and the `UIStoryboard` of the source `UIViewController`, but the code is much more readable and manageable.

Comment: It's good if this works for you. But in general, since the datasource is for the whole `UItableView` then it is not very flexible for reusing single cell on different tables.

Comment: It's built on top of a data source class I'm using that uses blocks to set up cells, just implemented the cell's delegate in a subclass